# Why can't I call this jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I need some help understanding some jQuery basics. I have a really simple function here but I can't call it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function ($) {
            callFunc();
        }
                function callFunc(){
                    alert("Function Called!");
                }
        );

 </script>
```

If I don't put the alert in it's own function it triggers the alert. When I wrap it in a function and give it a name and try to call it, it doesn't work. Please help, I've been looking all over for some straightforward ways of just creating and calling jQuery functions. I've tried passing in the $ as a parameter but no matter what I try, I can't seem to just create a simple function and call it. What am I doing wrong and how do I call my function?

Comment: And Yes... I have double checked to make sure that my jQuery library was connected properly and it is there.

Comment: Well, the code you posted is syntactically invalid. It cannot be executed at all. `a(b c)` is invalid. You either have to write `a(b, c)` or `a(b) c`, depending on your intention. In your case it should probably be `a(b) c`.

Comment: It works if you fix the syntax errors: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4j82x5vL/

Comment: I recommend to learn to use your browser's developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging. Also have a look at a JavaScript tutorial to learn the syntax of function calls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because of syntax error:

Your code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            callFunc();
        } //missing a closing ) for the JQuery(
                function callFunc(){
                    alert("Function Called!");
                }
        ); //extra )
```

Correct code:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
     callFunc();
 });

 function callFunc() {
     alert("Function Called!");
 }
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/tnhswf11/

If you want to have the function inside the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
     function callFunc() {
         alert("Function Called!");
     }
     callFunc();
 });
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/tnhswf11/1/

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy! So the functions themselves belong outside of the jQuery(); ?

Comment: For reference, see the syntax for [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

Comment: @Digital: you can quite happily put the functions inside the jQuery if you like, but between the curly braces `{` and `}`, *not* between the `}` and the `)`.

Comment: yes, you could have it inside but it has to be declared differently the function has to be declared before the call

Comment: You seem to have unintentionally reverted my edit. I recommend to use StackSnipptes for the demo.

Comment: @Digital: It doesn't really matter in this case where the function is declared, as long as it is *syntactically* valid. And the syntax has nothing to do with jQuery. If you are not very familiar with JavaScript, I recommend to read a JS tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error

Correct syntax:

```
     jQuery(function ($) {
           callFunc();

           function callFunc(){
                alert("Function Called!");
           }
     });
```

or:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
      callFunc();
 });

 function callFunc(){
      alert("Function Called!");
 }
```

Just a reminder. `jQuery(function ($) {});` is a short hand for `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`